# Apply custom vertical datum transformations to point cloud

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, point-cloud, vertical-transformation

My goal is to write a script that can add the geoidal undulations contained in a TIFF file (local geoid model) to a point cloud. I wrote the script below in Python that should perform this task using GDAL. Unfortunately I can't get it to work for some reason.

The TIFF file with the geoidal undulations is in WGS84 (EPSG:4326). The point cloud is in SIRGAS2000, UTM projection, zone 25S (EPSG:31985).

Here's the script:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np
import laspy

# Definir os caminhos dos arquivos
raster_file = "MDT-Desnivel-Imbituba.tif"
point_cloud_file = "Hgeo.las"
output_file = "Hnor.las"

# Carregar o arquivo raster
raster_dataset = gdal.Open(raster_file)
raster_band = raster_dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
raster_array = raster_band.ReadAsArray()

# Obter informações de projeção do raster
raster_projection = raster_dataset.GetProjection()
raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster_projection)

# Carregar o arquivo de nuvem de pontos
point_cloud = laspy.file.File(point_cloud_file, mode="r")
points = np.vstack((point_cloud.x, point_cloud.y, point_cloud.z)).T

# Criar uma nova nuvem de pontos para armazenar o resultado
new_point_cloud = laspy.file.File(output_file, mode="w", header=point_cloud.header)

# Projetar o raster no mesmo sistema de coordenadas da nuvem de pontos
target_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
target_srs.ImportFromEPSG(31985)  # EPSG:31985 (UTM SIRGAS2000 Zona 25S)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(raster_srs, target_srs)

# Somar a altitude do raster a cada ponto da nuvem de pontos
for point in points:
    # Projetar as coordenadas do ponto para o sistema de coordenadas do raster
    lon, lat, z = transform.TransformPoint(point[0], point[1], point[2])
    # Obter as coordenadas do pixel correspondente no raster
    px = int((lon - raster_dataset.GetGeoTransform()[0]) / raster_dataset.GetGeoTransform()[1])
    py = int((lat - raster_dataset.GetGeoTransform()[3]) / raster_dataset.GetGeoTransform()[5])
    # Obter a altitude correspondente do raster
    altitude = raster_array[py, px]
    # Somar a altitude ao ponto
    point[2] += altitude

# Copiar os dados da nuvem de pontos original para a nova nuvem de pontos
new_point_cloud.points = points

# Copiar os outros atributos da nuvem de pontos original para a nova nuvem de pontos
for name in point_cloud.point_format.names:
    if name != "X" and name != "Y" and name != "Z":
        new_point_cloud[name] = point_cloud[name]

# Fechar os arquivos
point_cloud.close()
new_point_cloud.close()
```

The errors that I'm getting are related to the lat values of the point cloud. "ERROR 1: PROJ: utm: Invalid latitude"

Can anyone help me to point where's the problem with the script? Apparently is something about the coordinate conversion, but I can't put my finger on it.

Here's the files that I'm using to test it out: https://ln5.sync.com/dl/97e4df3a0/hv4epqtm-g5gp9tyi-3b295f2w-hwrx7ss3